# Calling method using Azure scheduled webjob

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-webjobs

I want to call my method using Azure webjobs as shown. But I want to run it every 5 mins from March 13th to March 20th for local test purposes. I have followed instructions as per this [article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started/). I have created test storage account and then added connection strings to app.config and web.config files.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
      var host = new JobHost();
      // The following code will invoke a function called ManualTrigger and 
      // pass in data (value in this case) to the function
      host.Call(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("GetStockAndStoreToDB"), new { value = 20 });   
      //host.RunAndBlock();
    }
}
```

Here I want call my method GetStockAndStoreToDB.

```
public static void GetStockAndStoreToDB(TextWriter log, int value, [Queue("stockrequestqueue")] out string message)
{
    log.WriteLine("Function is invoked with value={0}", value);
    message = value.ToString();
    bool dbUpdate = false;
    string[] symbolArray = { "Yahoo", "Google", "Microsoft"};

    foreach (string symbol in symbolArray)
    {
        //Get Stock at closing
        var returnStock = Helper.GetDailyStock(symbol);
        message = symbol.ToString();
        //Store it to the DB            
        dbUpdate = Helper.SetHistoricStockToDB(returnStock);
    }
    log.WriteLine("Following message will be written on the Queue={0}", message);
}
```

And code for scheduled job (run every 5 minutues for test purpose only, once it starts working, I will change it to run daily once):

```
    {
        "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
        "webJobName": "StockWebJob",
        "startTime": "2015-03-13T16:00:00-05:00",
        "endTime": "2015-03-20T16:00:00-05:00", 
        "jobRecurrenceFrequency": "Minute", //"Day"
        "interval": 5, //1
        "runMode": "Scheduled"
    }
```

In my controller:

```
    private CloudQueue stockRequestQueue;

    public StockController()
    {
        InitializeStorage();
    }

    private void InitializeStorage()
    {            
        // Open storage account using credentials from .cscfg file.
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureWebJobsStorage"].ToString());
        //CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureWebJobsStorage"));

        // Get context object for working with queues, and 
        // set a default retry policy appropriate for a web user interface.
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        //queueClient.DefaultRequestOptions.RetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), 3);

        // Get a reference to the queue.
        stockRequestQueue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("stockrequestqueue");
        // Create the queue if it doesn't already exist
        stockRequestQueue.CreateIfNotExists();

        // Create a message and add it to the queue.
        CloudQueueMessage queueMessage = new CloudQueueMessage("Get Stock");
        stockRequestQueue.AddMessage(queueMessage);
    }
```

Please advice me where I am doing wrong, since the console creates once and stops, it doesn't run every 5 mins. If I use host.RunAndBlock(); then the console is open but it doesn't run anything.